# Hackerrank > Woman's CodeSprint 2 > stone division, Revisited ( recursive function)

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-challenge, recursion, time-limit-exceeded

[Problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/womens-codesprint-2/challenges/stone-division-2)

> You have a pile of `n` stones that you want to split into multiple piles, as well as a set, `S`, of `m` distinct integers. We define a *move* as follows:
>
> - First, choose a pile of stones. Let's say that the chosen pile contains `y`  stones.
> - Next, look for some `x` in `S` such that `x`<>`y`  and `y` is divisible by `x` (i.e., `x` is a factor of `y`); if such an `x` exists, you can split the pile into `x/y` equal smaller piles.
>
> You are given `q` queries where each query consists of `n` and `S`. For each query, calculate the maximum possible number of moves you can perform and print it on a new line.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer,`q`, denoting the number of queries. The  `2*q`subsequent lines describe each query in the following format:
>
> 1. The first line contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of `n` (the size of the initial pile in the query) and `m` (the size of the set in the query).
> 2. The second line contains  distinct space-separated integers describing the values in set `S`.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - `1 <= q <= 10`
> - `1 <= n <=` 10<sup>12</sup>
> - `2 <= m <= 1000`
> - 1 <= s<sub>i</sub> `<=` 10<sup>12</sup>
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each query, calculate the maximum possible number of moves you can perform and print it on a new line.
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> `1`
>
> `12` `3`
>
> `2` `3` `4`
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> `4`
>
> **Explanation 0**
>
> Initially there is a pile with `12` stones:
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

**My introduction of the algorithm**

The algorithm is one of medium level algorithm in hackerrank woman codesprint in Nov., 2016. It can be solved using recursive function and memorization.

In the contest, I did not write the recursive function because I overcooked the solution, ended up with a few hours scoring `0` from maximum score `50`. I learned the lesson, write less code, avoid complicated code, think recursively. And I documented the study how to think recursively and tried to learn the simple recursive function.

After 3 months of the contest, I reviewed the algorithm again, and spent one hour to rewrite the C# code based on one of submissions I studied 3 months ago. Please help me review the algorithm.

The C# code passes all test cases using hackerrank online judge.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace stoneDivisionStudyCode
{
    /*
    * 
    * Problem statement:
    * https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/womens-codesprint-2/challenges/stone-division-2
    *        
    */
    class StoneDivsion
    {
        public static Dictionary<long, long> memo = new Dictionary<long, long>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessInput();
            //RunTestcase(); 
        }

        public static void ProcessInput()
        {
            int queries = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int query = 0; query < queries; query++)
            {
                memo.Clear();

                string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

                long n = long.Parse(input[0]);
                int m = int.Parse(input[1]);

                long[] predefinedSet = new long[1003];

                predefinedSet = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), long.Parse);

                long answer = CalculateMaximumPossibleMoves(n, predefinedSet, m);

                Console.WriteLine(answer);
            }
        }

        /*
         * 1
         * 12 3
         * 2  3  4
         * Go over problem statement and explanation 
         * of sample test case
         */
        public static void RunTestcase()
        {
            memo.Clear();

            long n = 12;
            int m = 3;

            var predefinedSet = new long[3] { 2, 3, 4 };

            long answer = CalculateMaximumPossibleMoves(n, predefinedSet, m);

            Debug.Assert(answer == 4);
        }

        /*
        * Recursive and memorization two techniques                                   
        *             
        * Recursive function design - 
        * 
        * Timeout issue - using memorization
        * maximum size of integers < 1000
        * 1 <= m <= 1000 
        */
        public static long CalculateMaximumPossibleMoves(
            long pile,
            long[] predefinedSet,
            int sizeOfPredefinedSet)
        {
            // look up memorization dictionary 
            if (memo.ContainsKey(pile))
            {
                return memo[pile];
            }

            // go over all possible options to find maximum number of moves
            long maximumNumberOfMoves = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfPredefinedSet; i++)
            {
                long divisor = predefinedSet[i];

                if (pile % divisor != 0 || (pile / divisor <= 1))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // solve a subproblem using recurisve function - a small pile
                long numberOfMoves = CalculateMaximumPossibleMoves(divisor, predefinedSet, sizeOfPredefinedSet);

                // how many piles - count in the factor of piles
                // first divide into small piles, then each small pile will be processed. 
                numberOfMoves = 1 + (pile / divisor) * numberOfMoves;

                // keep the maximum one only
                maximumNumberOfMoves = Math.Max(maximumNumberOfMoves, numberOfMoves);
            }

            memo[pile] = maximumNumberOfMoves;

            return maximumNumberOfMoves;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am learning recursive function. Please help! I like to share the blog I wrote in Nov. 2016 how I studied recursive function after the contest, and then found the website codereview.stackexchange.com through the study. I choose to share it in the comment instead of question, because some people may find it unrelated. :-) http://juliachencoding.blogspot.ca/2016/11/hackerrank-woman-codesprint2-stone_20.html

Comment: If the code passes all test cases, why have you tagged the question as [tag:time-limit-exceeded]?

Comment: The code I asked for review is my third practice, because the time limited is 3 seconds for the algorithm in the contest in general on hackerrank, the size of q, n, m make a lot of implementation time-out, use recursive function with memorization will not time out. Otherwise, no need to use memorization. Hopefully, I understand your question.